# Flutter: Build failed with an exception

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, flutter

I am trying to use FirebaseAuth in a flutter application. I can use Firestore service but when i include firebase_auth depedency in pubspec.yaml file i got the following exception.

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'.
> java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Unable to merge dex
* Try:Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get
more log output.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
```

here is my pubspec.yaml file

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  intl: ^0.15.6
  #firebase_core: ^0.2.2
  google_sign_in:
    git:
      url: http://github.com/jahirhstu/flutter_plugins.git
      path: packages/google_sign_in
  #firebase_analytics: 
  #  git:
  #    url: http://github.com/jahirhstu/flutter_plugins.git
  #    path: packages/firebase_analytics
  firebase_auth:
    git:
      url: http://github.com/jahirhstu/flutter_plugins.git
      path: packages/firebase_auth
  cloud_firestore:
    git:
      url: http://github.com/jahirhstu/flutter_plugins.git
      path: packages/cloud_firestore
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.0
  shrine_images: 1.0.0

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
```

Answer (score 17):

Well, I was trying to solve it and what I did was:

*1.-Reinstall Flutter

2.-Reinstall Dart SDK

3.-Download Gradle 5.1.1

4.-Create a new Application with Firebase and include dependencies

5.-Compile again*

And all of these didnt work.

Then I did:

6.-Copy next lines at the end of gradle.properties

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

7.-Changes on file app\build.gradle

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 28

...

defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 28
    multiDexEnabled true
    ...
}
```

}

8.-Optionally you can add code inside subproject{} in file android\build.gradle

```
subprojects {
    ...
    gradle.projectsEvaluated {
        tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
            options.compilerArgs << "-Xlint:deprecation" << "-Xlint:unchecked"
        }
    }
}
```

9.-Go to terminal and launch command

```
flutter clean
```

10.-Run your app.

Hope will be helpful

Comment: Hello, I follow all your steps now it showing me one error
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugKotlin'.
Please help me! Thanks

Answer (score 4):

In your Project folder > android > app > build.gradle:
add the following Line in defaultConfig { .... multiDexEnabled true }

[image]

Comment: It did resolve the build error but application is not running in the emulator. Getting the message "ApplicationName keeps stopping."

Comment: Run Command  'flutter clean' in the Project Directory & build Again.

Comment: After issuing "flutter run" command in the emulator instead of running the application a message appear that says "ApplicationName keeps stopping". ApplicationName is my appname.

Comment: I restarted the emulator, issued flutter clean and then flutter run again. Still getting the same error.

Comment: Upgrade your Flutter - 'flutter upgrade' if not upgraded.

Comment: also in same file(build.gradle) in the end - add 'com.google.gms.googleservices.GoogleServicesPlugin.config.disableVersionCheck = true' see if this helps.

Comment: try this: flutter run --enable-software-rendering

Comment: In my case, I need to set 'compileSdkVersion' to 28

Answer (score 0):

try doing this in the /android/app/build.gradle file:

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        // ...
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 28
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
}

dependencies {
  implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If none of the above technique works simply downgrade your gradle build level. This will solve your problem.

```
dependencies {
    `classpath` '`com.android.tools.build:gradle:**3.5.0**`'
}
```