# Firestore library creates error on flutter for iOS and android

Tags: firebase, dart, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-dependencies

I try to build this code:

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(new FlutterChatApp());

class FlutterChatApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      title: "Flutter Chat App",
      home: Scaffold(
        body: RaisedButton(
          child : Text('edpeo'),
          onPressed:(){
           print("salut");
          }
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

and it works only on android.
On iOS I get this in the debug console even after 'flutter clean', but I did not add Firestore library and any other one in the pubspec.yaml file:

```
Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone XR in debug mode...
Xcode build done.                                            6,8s
Failed to build iOS app
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
** BUILD FAILED **
Xcode's output:
↳
=== BUILD TARGET cloud_firestore OF PROJECT Pods WITH CONFIGURATION Debug ===
In file included from /Users/evvon/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/cloud_firestore-0.8.2+1/ios/Classes/CloudFirestorePlugin.m:5:
In file included from /Users/evvon/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/cloud_firestore-0.8.2+1/ios/Classes/CloudFirestorePlugin.h:5:
In file included from /Users/evvon/project flutter/chart_test/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/Flutter/Flutter/Flutter.h:44:
In file included from /Users/evvon/project flutter/chart_test/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/Flutter/Flutter/FlutterAppDelegate.h:11:
/Users/evvon/project flutter/chart_test/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/Flutter/Flutter/FlutterPlugin.h:100:42: warning: 'UIUserNotificationSettings' is only available on iOS 8.0 or newer [-Wunguarded-availability]
didRegisterUserNotificationSettings:(UIUserNotificationSettings*)notificationSettings;
^
In module 'UIKit' imported from /Users/evvon/project flutter/chart_test/ios/Pods/Target Support Files/cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore-prefix.pch:2:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator12.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIUserNotificationSettings.h:44:12: note: 'UIUserNotificationSettings' has been explicitly marked partial here
@interface UIUserNotificationSettings : NSObject
^
In file included from /Users/evvon/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/cloud_firestore-0.8.2+1/ios/Classes/CloudFirestorePlugin.m:5:
In file included from /Users/evvon/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/cloud_firestore-0.8.2+1/ios/Classes/CloudFirestorePlugin.h:5:
In file included from /Users/evvon/project flutter/chart_test/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/Flutter/Flutter/Flutter.h:44:
In file included from /Users/evvon/project flutter/chart_test/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/Flutter/Flutter/FlutterAppDelegate.h:11:
/Users/evvon/project flutter/chart_test/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/Flutter/Flutter/FlutterPlugin.h:99:1: note: annotate 'application:didRegisterUserNotificationSettings:' with an availability attribute to silence this warning
- (void)application:(UIApplication*)application
^
/Users/evvon/project flutter/chart_test/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/Flutter/Flutter/FlutterPlugin.h:115:44: warning: 'UIBackgroundFetchResult' is only available on iOS 7.0 or newer [-Wunguarded-availability]
fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult result))completionHandler;
^
In module 'UIKit' imported from /Users/evvon/project flutter/chart_test/ios/Pods/Target Support Files/cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore-prefix.pch:2:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator12.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIApplication.h:75:29: note: 'UIBackgroundFetchResult' has been explicitly marked partial here
typedef NS_ENUM(NSUInteger, UIBackgroundFetchResult) {
^
In file included from /Users/evvon/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/cloud_firestore-0.8.2+1/ios/Classes/CloudFirestorePlugin.m:5:
In file included from /Users/evvon/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/cloud_firestore-0.8.2+1/ios/Classes/CloudFirestorePlugin.h:5:
In file included from /Users/evvon/project flutter/chart_test/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/Flutter/Flutter/Flutter.h:44:
In file included from /Users/evvon/project flutter/chart_test/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/Flutter/Flutter/FlutterAppDelegate.h:11:
/Users/evvon/project flutter/chart_test/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/Flutter/Flutter/FlutterPlugin.h:113:1: note: annotate 'application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:' with an availability attribute to silence this warning
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication*)application
^
/Users/evvon/project flutter/chart_test/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/Flutter/Flutter/FlutterPlugin.h:168:49: warning: 'UIBackgroundFetchResult' is only available on iOS 7.0 or newer [-Wunguarded-availability]
performFetchWithCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult result))completionHandler;
^
In module 'UIKit' imported from /Users/evvon/project flutter/chart_test/ios/Pods/Target Support Files/cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore-prefix.pch:2:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator12.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIApplication.h:75:29: note: 'UIBackgroundFetchResult' has been explicitly marked partial here
typedef NS_ENUM(NSUInteger, UIBackgroundFetchResult) {
^
In file included from /Users/evvon/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/cloud_firestore-0.8.2+1/ios/Classes/CloudFirestorePlugin.m:5:
In file included from /Users/evvon/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/cloud_firestore-0.8.2+1/ios/Classes/CloudFirestorePlugin.h:5:
In file included from /Users/evvon/project flutter/chart_test/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/Flutter/Flutter/Flutter.h:44:
In file included from /Users/evvon/project flutter/chart_test/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/Flutter/Flutter/FlutterAppDelegate.h:11:
/Users/evvon/project flutter/chart_test/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/Flutter/Flutter/FlutterPlugin.h:167:1: note: annotate 'application:performFetchWithCompletionHandler:' with an availability attribute to silence this warning
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication*)application
^
/Users/evvon/project flutter/chart_test/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/Flutter/Flutter/FlutterPlugin.h:176:27: warning: 'NSUserActivity' is only available on iOS 8.0 or newer [-Wunguarded-availability]
continueUserActivity:(NSUserActivity*)userActivity
^
In module 'Foundation' imported from /Users/evvon/project flutter/chart_test/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/Flutter/Flutter/FlutterBinaryMessenger.h:8:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator12.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSUserActivity.h:20:12: note: 'NSUserActivity' has been explicitly marked partial here
@interface NSUserActivity : NSObject
^
In file included from /Users/evvon/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/cloud_firestore-0.8.2+1/ios/Classes/CloudFirestorePlugin.m:5:
In file included from /Users/evvon/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/cloud_firestore-0.8.2+1/ios/Classes/CloudFirestorePlugin.h:5:
In file included from /Users/evvon/project flutter/chart_test/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/Flutter/Flutter/Flutter.h:44:
In file included from /Users/evvon/project flutter/chart_test/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/Flutter/Flutter/FlutterAppDelegate.h:11:
/Users/evvon/project flutter/chart_test/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/Flutter/Flutter/FlutterPlugin.h:175:1: note: annotate 'application:continueUserActivity:restorationHandler:' with an availability attribute to silence this warning
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication*)application
^
In file included from /Users/evvon/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/cloud_firestore-0.8.2+1/ios/Classes/CloudFirestorePlugin.m:5:
In file included from /Users/evvon/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/cloud_firestore-0.8.2+1/ios/Classes/CloudFirestorePlugin.h:5:
In file included from /Users/evvon/project flutter/chart_test/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/Flutter/Flutter/Flutter.h:54:
/Users/evvon/project flutter/chart_test/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/Flutter/Flutter/FlutterPluginAppLifeCycleDelegate.h:70:42: warning: 'UIUserNotificationSettings' is only available on iOS 8.0 or newer [-Wunguarded-availability]
didRegisterUserNotificationSettings:(UIUserNotificationSettings*)notificationSettings;
^
In module 'UIKit' imported from /Users/evvon/project flutter/chart_test/ios/Pods/Target Support Files/cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore-prefix.pch:2:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator12.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIUserNotificationSettings.h:44:12: note: 'UIUserNotificationSettings' has been explicitly marked partial here
@interface UIUserNotificationSettings : NSObject
^
In file included from /Users/evvon/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/cloud_firestore-0.8.2+1/ios/Classes/CloudFirestorePlugin.m:5:
In file included from /Users/evvon/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/cloud_firestore-0.8.2+1/ios/Classes/CloudFirestorePlugin.h:5:
In file included from /Users/evvon/project flutter/chart_test/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/Flutter/Flutter/Flutter.h:54:
/Users/evvon/project flutter/chart_test/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/Flutter/Flutter/FlutterPluginAppLifeCycleDelegate.h:69:1: note: annotate 'application:didRegisterUserNotificationSettings:' with an availability attribute to silence this warning
- (void)application:(UIApplication*)application
^
/Users/evvon/project flutter/chart_test/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/Flutter/Flutter/FlutterPluginAppLifeCycleDelegate.h:83:44: warning: 'UIBackgroundFetchResult' is only available on iOS 7.0 or newer [-Wunguarded-availability]
fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult result))completionHandler;
^
In module 'UIKit' imported from /Users/evvon/project flutter/chart_test/ios/Pods/Target Support Files/cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore-prefix.pch:2:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator12.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIApplication.h:75:29: note: 'UIBackgroundFetchResult' has been explicitly marked partial here
typedef NS_ENUM(NSUInteger, UIBackgroundFetchResult) {
^
In file included from /Users/evvon/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/cloud_firestore-0.8.2+1/ios/Classes/CloudFirestorePlugin.m:5:
In file included from /Users/evvon/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/cloud_firestore-0.8.2+1/ios/Classes/CloudFirestorePlugin.h:5:
In file included from /Users/evvon/project flutter/chart_test/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/Flutter/Flutter/Flutter.h:54:
/Users/evvon/project flutter/chart_test/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/Flutter/Flutter/FlutterPluginAppLifeCycleDelegate.h:81:1: note: annotate 'application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:' with an availability attribute to silence this warning
- (void)application:(UIApplication*)application
^
/Users/evvon/project flutter/chart_test/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/Flutter/Flutter/FlutterPluginAppLifeCycleDelegate.h:139:49: warning: 'UIBackgroundFetchResult' is only available on iOS 7.0 or newer [-Wunguarded-availability]
performFetchWithCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult result))completionHandler;
^
In module 'UIKit' imported from /Users/evvon/project flutter/chart_test/ios/Pods/Target Support Files/cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore-prefix.pch:2:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator12.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIApplication.h:75:29: note: 'UIBackgroundFetchResult' has been explicitly marked partial here
typedef NS_ENUM(NSUInteger, UIBackgroundFetchResult) {
^
In file included from /Users/evvon/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/cloud_firestore-0.8.2+1/ios/Classes/CloudFirestorePlugin.m:5:
In file included from /Users/evvon/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/cloud_firestore-0.8.2+1/ios/Classes/CloudFirestorePlugin.h:5:
In file included from /Users/evvon/project flutter/chart_test/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/Flutter/Flutter/Flutter.h:54:
/Users/evvon/project flutter/chart_test/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/Flutter/Flutter/FlutterPluginAppLifeCycleDelegate.h:138:1: note: annotate 'application:performFetchWithCompletionHandler:' with an availability attribute to silence this warning
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication*)application
^
/Users/evvon/project flutter/chart_test/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/Flutter/Flutter/FlutterPluginAppLifeCycleDelegate.h:147:27: warning: 'NSUserActivity' is only available on iOS 8.0 or newer [-Wunguarded-availability]
continueUserActivity:(NSUserActivity*)userActivity
^
In module 'Foundation' imported from /Users/evvon/project flutter/chart_test/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/Flutter/Flutter/FlutterBinaryMessenger.h:8:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator12.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSUserActivity.h:20:12: note: 'NSUserActivity' has been explicitly marked partial here
@interface NSUserActivity : NSObject
^
In file included from /Users/evvon/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/cloud_firestore-0.8.2+1/ios/Classes/CloudFirestorePlugin.m:5:
In file included from /Users/evvon/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/cloud_firestore-0.8.2+1/ios/Classes/CloudFirestorePlugin.h:5:
In file included from /Users/evvon/project flutter/chart_test/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/Flutter/Flutter/Flutter.h:54:
/Users/evvon/project flutter/chart_test/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/Flutter/Flutter/FlutterPluginAppLifeCycleDelegate.h:146:1: note: annotate 'application:continueUserActivity:restorationHandler:' with an availability attribute to silence this warning
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication*)application
^
/Users/evvon/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/cloud_firestore-0.8.2+1/ios/Classes/CloudFirestorePlugin.m:50:22: error: no visible @interface for 'FIRQuery' declares the selector 'queryWhereField:arrayContains:'
query = [query queryWhereField:fieldName arrayContains:value];
~~~~~ ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/evvon/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/cloud_firestore-0.8.2+1/ios/Classes/CloudFirestorePlugin.m:117:45: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'NSUInteger' (aka 'unsigned long') to 'int' [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
@"oldIndex" : [NSNumber numberWithInt:documentChange.oldIndex],
~                       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/evvon/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/cloud_firestore-0.8.2+1/ios/Classes/CloudFirestorePlugin.m:118:45: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'NSUInteger' (aka 'unsigned long') to 'int' [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
@"newIndex" : [NSNumber numberWithInt:documentChange.newIndex],
~                       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/evvon/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/cloud_firestore-0.8.2+1/ios/Classes/CloudFirestorePlugin.m:174:21: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'NSUInteger' (aka 'unsigned long') to 'UInt32' (aka 'unsigned int') [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
[self writeSize:blob.length];
~               ^~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/evvon/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/cloud_firestore-0.8.2+1/ios/Classes/CloudFirestorePlugin.m:221:29: error: no known class method for selector 'fieldValueForArrayUnion:'
return [FIRFieldValue fieldValueForArrayUnion:[self readValue]];
^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/evvon/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/cloud_firestore-0.8.2+1/ios/Classes/CloudFirestorePlugin.m:224:29: error: no known class method for selector 'fieldValueForArrayRemove:'
return [FIRFieldValue fieldValueForArrayRemove:[self readValue]];
^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/evvon/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/cloud_firestore-0.8.2+1/ios/Classes/CloudFirestorePlugin.m:303:7: warning: block implicitly retains 'self'; explicitly mention 'self' to indicate this is intended behavior [-Wimplicit-retain-self]
transactions[transactionId] = transaction;
^
self->
/Users/evvon/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/cloud_firestore-0.8.2+1/ios/Classes/CloudFirestorePlugin.m:310:29: warning: block implicitly retains 'self'; explicitly mention 'self' to indicate this is intended behavior [-Wimplicit-retain-self]
transactionResults[transactionId] = doTransactionResult;
^
self->
/Users/evvon/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/cloud_firestore-0.8.2+1/ios/Classes/CloudFirestorePlugin.m:317:14: warning: block implicitly retains 'self'; explicitly mention 'self' to indicate this is intended behavior [-Wimplicit-retain-self]
return transactionResults[transactionId];
^
self->
/Users/evvon/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/cloud_firestore-0.8.2+1/ios/Classes/CloudFirestorePlugin.m:331:37: warning: block implicitly retains 'self'; explicitly mention 'self' to indicate this is intended behavior [-Wimplicit-retain-self]
FIRTransaction *transaction = transactions[transactionId];
^
self->
/Users/evvon/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/cloud_firestore-0.8.2+1/ios/Classes/CloudFirestorePlugin.m:355:37: warning: block implicitly retains 'self'; explicitly mention 'self' to indicate this is intended behavior [-Wimplicit-retain-self]
FIRTransaction *transaction = transactions[transactionId];
^
self->
/Users/evvon/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/cloud_firestore-0.8.2+1/ios/Classes/CloudFirestorePlugin.m:364:37: warning: block implicitly retains 'self'; explicitly mention 'self' to indicate this is intended behavior [-Wimplicit-retain-self]
FIRTransaction *transaction = transactions[transactionId];
^
self->
/Users/evvon/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/cloud_firestore-0.8.2+1/ios/Classes/CloudFirestorePlugin.m:373:37: warning: block implicitly retains 'self'; explicitly mention 'self' to indicate this is intended behavior [-Wimplicit-retain-self]
FIRTransaction *transaction = transactions[transactionId];
^
self->
18 warnings and 3 errors generated.
Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone XR.
Exited (sigterm)
```

When I finally add Firestore dependency in pubspec.yaml file without importing it in the code, I get the same issue in iOS and on android I get this:

```
Launching lib/main.dart on Android SDK built for x86 in debug mode...
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedFolders(FileCollection)
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedFolders(FileCollection)
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedFolders(FileCollection)
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedFolders(FileCollection)
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedFolders(FileCollection)

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'.
> java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Unable to merge dex

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 7s
Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
Exited (sigterm)
```

And when I enable multiDexEnabled true, I get this output:

```
Launching lib/main.dart on Android SDK built for x86 in debug mode...
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedFolders(FileCollection)
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedFolders(FileCollection)
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedFolders(FileCollection)
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedFolders(FileCollection)
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedFolders(FileCollection)
Dex: Error converting bytecode to dex:
Cause: com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Landroid/arch/core/util/Function;
    UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
    com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Landroid/arch/core/util/Function;

com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Landroid/arch/core/util/Function;
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.readSortableTypes(DexMerger.java:661)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.getSortedTypes(DexMerger.java:616)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeClassDefs(DexMerger.java:598)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:171)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:198)
    at com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerCallable.call(DexArchiveMergerCallable.java:61)
    at com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerCallable.call(DexArchiveMergerCallable.java:36)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask$AdaptedCallable.exec(ForkJoinTask.java:1424)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:289)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1056)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1692)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:157)

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithDexMergerForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Landroid/arch/core/util/Function;

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 10s
Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
Exited (sigterm)
```

Comment: you need to enable multiDexEnabled true - https://stackoverflow.com/a/52409800/10269042

Comment: I tried your solution, it still does not work.