# Flutter : AAPT2 aapt2-3.5.0-5435860-windows Daemon #2: Unexpected standard output: Ready

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, dart

the app runed without error before i connect it to firebase . after i connected to the firebase this error comes up

its the hello world app(default example app)

```
 AAPT2 aapt2-3.5.0-5435860-windows Daemon #2: Unexpected standard output: Ready
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
AAPT2 aapt2-3.5.0-5435860-windows Daemon #1: Unexpected standard output: Ready
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...

Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...

Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
* What went wrong:
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
> Multiple task action failures occurred:
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
   > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade       
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
      > AAPT2 aapt2-3.5.0-5435860-windows Daemon #0: Daemon startup failed
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
        This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
   > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
      > AAPT2 aapt2-3.5.0-5435860-windows Daemon #1: Daemon startup failed
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
        This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
   > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade       
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
      > AAPT2 aapt2-3.5.0-5435860-windows Daemon #2: Daemon startup failed
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
        This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...

Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
* Try:
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...

Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...

Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
BUILD FAILED in 16m 29s
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...

Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'... Done                      1030.9s (!)
The built failed likely due to AndroidX incompatibilities in a plugin. The tool is about to try using      
Jetfier to solve the incompatibility.
Building plugin cloud_firestore...
Exception: The plugin cloud_firestore could not be built due to the issue above.
Running Gradle task 'assembleAarRelease'...
```

build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.50'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}


                  -
```

build.gradle

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.example.mobiboy"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1'
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

what can i do to clear this error

i tried flutter clean , flutter pub get upgrade
the error is come after adding to firebase

Answer (score 0):

steps :

1. Try adding this line In your Project folder > android > app > build.gradle, add the following Line inside defaultConfig

   multiDexEnabled true
2. Then upgrade gradle dependency in the android/build.gradle file: classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.1'
3. Run flutter clean and rebuild your project

Comment: bro the version is upgraded  classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0'

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59573543/7056002 try this