# Mistakes happen when building Flutter APK

Tags: flutter, build.gradle, apk

**Hello I just Finished Programing using Flutter platform So when I was write my code and running the code everything working well But when  i need to Building APK show my Error and cant Building  i don't no what's the problem and How can i Fixed**

**please any Body help my**

**This is the Error that Showing****

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':unique_identifier:verifyReleaseResources'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
   > Android resource linking failed
     C:\Users\Ahmed\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\aafef0879a74786e0e084911877b2a52\core-1.1.0\res\values\values.xml:142:5-173:25: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/fontVariationSettings not found.

     C:\Users\Ahmed\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\aafef0879a74786e0e084911877b2a52\core-1.1.0\res\values\values.xml:142:5-173:25: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/ttcIndex not found.


* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 14m 8s
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'... Done                     851.9s (!)
The built failed likely due to AndroidX incompatibilities in a plugin. The tool is about to try using Jetfier to solve
the incompatibility.
Building plugin cloud_firestore...
The plugin cloud_firestore could not be built due to the issue above.
Running Gradle task 'assembleAarRelease'...
```

**This is my Bulid.Gradle**

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new FileNotFoundException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 29

    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.Biz.appExit.docFlow"
        minSdkVersion 19
       multiDexEnabled true
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }

  
    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:17.5.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:18.0.0' 
     implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.1'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you can read in error message, the plugin you used has some AndroidX incompabilities. Try to execute `flutter packages get` and `flutter clean`, maybe something cached. Then try build again.

Also look at this link [How to fix flutter AndroidX incompatibility?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56539737/how-to-fix-flutter-androidx-incompatibility)

Comment: Try to read the error text. The plugin is `cloud firestore`.

Comment: i tired your  solution but Nothing has changed  .... I used cloud firestore in my app but when i use this Error not showed  me

Comment: @mohmmed ali, look at the link in answer