# Flutter tried to create the file android\settings_aar.gradle, but failed

Tags: android, flutter

My application was working fine. After some time when I started android studio to run the application it started showing me errors that the build failed likely due to AndroidX incompatibilities in a plugin. The tool is about to try using Jetifier to solve the incompatibility. Is there any way I can get this solved?
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.

> Android resource linking failed
> C:\Users\Admin.nisfanzats\Desktop\Flutter\Clima-Flutter-master\build\app\intermediates\merged_manifests\debug\AndroidManifest.xml:17: AAPT: error: unexpected element  found in .

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 14s
The build failed likely due to AndroidX incompatibilities in a plugin. The tool is about to try using Jetifier to solve the incompatibility.
✏️  Creating `android\settings_aar.gradle`...
[!] Flutter tried to create the file `android\settings_aar.gradle`, but failed.
To manually update `settings.gradle`, follow these steps:

```
1. Copy `settings.gradle` as `settings_aar.gradle`
2. Remove the following code from `settings_aar.gradle`:

    def localPropertiesFile = new File(rootProject.projectDir, "local.properties")
    def properties = new Properties()

    assert localPropertiesFile.exists()
    localPropertiesFile.withReader("UTF-8") { reader -> properties.load(reader) }

    def flutterSdkPath = properties.getProperty("flutter.sdk")
    assert flutterSdkPath != null, "flutter.sdk not set in local.properties"
    apply from: "$flutterSdkPath/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/app_plugin_loader.gradle"
```

Exception: Please create the file and run this command again.

[enter[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q9QXj.png) image description here][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FMe1x.png)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56539737/how-to-fix-flutter-androidx-incompatibility

Comment: @UsamaAltaf i tried all those. it didnt work

Answer (score 1):

In your android directory, follow the steps below:

1. Create a new file **settings_aar.gradle**
2. paste or type this code `include ':app'` in the **settings_aar.gradle** file
3. save the file